# Left Join does not give expected results

Tags: mysql

I need help with Left Join in this specific case.

Table Creation statements:

```
 create temporary table `temp_table_A` ( `txn_dt` date not null, `id` int not null, `key` varchar(32) NOT NULL, `val` int NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`txn_dt`, `id`));
 create temporary table `temp_table_B` ( `txn_dt` date not null, `id` int not null, `grade` varchar(32) NOT NULL ,  PRIMARY KEY (`txn_dt`, `id`));
```

Data Population statements:

```
 insert into temp_table_A values ( 20190102,  1 , 'AA' , 10 );
 insert into temp_table_A values ( 20190102, 2 , 'BB' , 11 );
 insert into temp_table_A values ( 20190102, 3 , 'CC' , 12 );

 insert into temp_table_B values ( 20190103, 2 , 'CAT1');
 insert into temp_table_B values ( 20190103, 4 , 'CAT2'  );
```

### Query being used to get the data :

```
select key, val , grade
from 
    temp_table_A a
        LEFT JOIN
    temp_table_B b on a.id = b.id 
where a.txn_dt = 20190102 
and b.txn_dt = 20190103
and a.key = 'AA'
```

Expected results :

```
key           val        grade
----------   ----------  -------
AA           10          null

Actual results :
No rows returned
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b.txn_dt` is null. The condition on `b.txn_dt` removes your expected result from the result set. You'll need

```sql
and (b.txn_dt = 20190103 or b.txn_dt is null)
```

I didn't test it but alternative may be moving the condition on `b.txn_id` into the join:

```sql
LEFT JOIN temp_table_B b on (a.id = b.id and b.txn_dt = 20190103)
```

Comment: I'd go with option 2